# Copy files from node_modules to dist dir

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to copy library from `node_modules` to `dist` folder using `html-webpack-plugin`, the library name is `wsrpc-python`

That's my webpack config, I set `file-loader` but it doesn't help.

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
        : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  externals: {
    "wsrpc-python": "WSRPC",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
        include: [
          resolve('src'),
          resolve('test'),
          resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        include: [resolve('src/icons')],
        options: {
          symbolId: 'icon-[name]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        exclude: [resolve('src/icons')],
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /wsrpc-python\/js\//,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding onto @tony19's answer, you need to set a `to` and `from` path in `copy-webpack-plugin`.

It should look like this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'node_modules/wsrpc-python/*.js', to: '/dist' },
]),
```

Comment: [The constructor has changed](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/): it now includes `patterns: [..]`

Answer (score 6):

By default CopyWebpackPlugin will look for the file in the current dir, to provide the right dir we need to use `require.resolve('your-package-name/dir/file-name')`

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: require.resolve('my-package-name/dist/index.css'),
        to: '[name].min.css'
      }]
    })
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`CopyWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#root) instead:

*webpack.config.js:*

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ...
    new CopyPlugin([
      'node_modules/wsrpc-python/*.js',
    ]),
  ],
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/copy-webpack-plugin-demo)

Comment: Doesn't work, I even tried `writeToDisk` option, but still nothing

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a link to a GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: CopyWebpackPlugin didn't work for me either. I just used a custom inline plugin, like so: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/c473c60ea0f10a2620f2d9d00c06e6c7

Answer (score 1):

CopyWebpackPlugin didn't work for me either.

I just use a custom inline plugin, like so: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/c473c60ea0f10a2620f2d9d00c06e6c7